# Does it make sense to connect my i7-3770 (not K) to 2400Mhz DDR3 RAM when using Z77 Pro4-M?

Tags: compatibility, hardware-rec

I just found this in [my CPU spec](http://ark.intel.com/products/65719/Intel-Core-i7-3770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz):

Memory Types:   DDR3 1333/1600

Does that mean I can't connect DDR3 RAM clocked at 2400mhz? If I can, will it be downclocked to 1600 mhz?

Comment: The memory frequency limitations will be based on your motherboard not your CPU.  It only matters if your CPU is unlocked or not.

Comment: @Ramhound: what does this part of the spec mean then?

Comment: @Ramhound also, is 3770 (not K) locked? What's the maximum ram frequency that's worth buying for this set?

Comment: @Ramhound would you have more information on that? I was under the impression that in current generations the memory controller (which would be responsible for the clocking etc.) became part of the CPU. Sure there would be some base circuitry left on the board but that should've have much of an impact?

Comment: Motherboard determined it in the sense of overclocking support, CPU either allows overclocking or doesn't allow it.  An non-K Intel CPU isn't unlocked

Comment: @Ramhound so long story short, if I bought DDR3-2400 for this motherboard and CPU, I'd have it automatically downclocked?

Comment: As I indicated that depends on the motherboard.  The only thing certain is that you won't be able to overclock it past the frequency of your DDR3-2400 since you don't have an unlocked CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean I can't connect DDR3 RAM clocked at 2400mhz? If I can, will it be downclocked to 1600 mhz?

No, it does not. Because 1600 and 1333 in this case, aren't clock speeds in MHz at all. They are memory module standard numbers.

> Does this mean that KHX24C11T3K4 (DDR3-2400) would work with this setup?

Yes. It does. According to [KHX24C11T3K4 documentations](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KHX24C11T3K4_16X.pdf), this memory module consists of four JEDEC DDR3-1333 profiles. You already said your CPU supports this profile. [You motherboard supports it too](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Pro4-M/?cat=Specifications).

**Important Update:** According to my investigation, there are more factors involved than just the CPU and the motherboard's stated support. Make sure you purchase from a vendor with a return policy or do the RAM upgrade by taking your box to a PC shop, where the shopkeeper can try several modules on your box with relative freedom.

Comment: Does this mean that KHX24C11T3K4 (DDR3-2400) would work with this setup?

Comment: I have asked my colleagues; I am waiting for their answer. According to your motherboard's documentation, this module is compatible with the motherboard.

Comment: I wonder if compatible means "it works" or "it works at advertised speed". Anyway, thanks for asking your colleagues.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, here's what Mattia from Intel support said: "What I meant with that sentence is that the Processor has not been tested on that high Frequency. We would not suggest to try that has it might stress the CPU and burn "